# undefined reference to `vtkRenderingOpenGL2_AutoInit_Construct()' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: linker, linker-errors, vtk, point-cloud-library, catkin

I have a linker error, I'm not really sure what does this exactly mean but thats what I read online. So please I need help from experts, I'm getting an error as below

```
CMakeFiles/run_emvs.dir/src/main.cpp.o: In function 

`vtkRenderingCore_AutoInit::~vtkRenderingCore_AutoInit()':
/usr/include/vtk-6.2/vtkRenderingCoreModule.h:41: undefined reference to `vtkRenderingOpenGL2_AutoInit_Destruct()'
CMakeFiles/run_emvs.dir/src/main.cpp.o: In function `vtkRenderingCore_AutoInit::vtkRenderingCore_AutoInit()':
/usr/include/vtk-6.2/vtkRenderingCoreModule.h:41: undefined reference to `vtkRenderingOpenGL2_AutoInit_Construct()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
rpg_emvs/mapper_emvs/CMakeFiles/run_emvs.dir/build.make:623: recipe for target '/home/ubuntu/emvs_ws/devel/lib/mapper_emvs/run_emvs' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/ubuntu/emvs_ws/devel/lib/mapper_emvs/run_emvs] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:6871: recipe for target 'rpg_emvs/mapper_emvs/CMakeFiles/run_emvs.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [rpg_emvs/mapper_emvs/CMakeFiles/run_emvs.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[100%] Built target realtime_emvs
Makefile:140: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j8 -l8" failed
```

it happens when catkin_make reaches 100% !

Comment: Just a hint >>>> the problem seems to happen because of the header files I don;t know which one exactly but removing these solves the issue #include <pcl/point_types.h>
#include <pcl_ros/point_cloud.h>
#include <pcl/io/pcd_io.h>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>
#include <pcl/filters/voxel_grid.h>
#include <pcl/pcl_base.h>
//#include <pcl/visualization/pcl_visualizer.h>
#include <pcl/ModelCoefficients.h>
#include <pcl/sample_consensus/method_types.h>
#include <pcl/sample_consensus/model_types.h>
#include <pcl/segmentation/sac_segmentation.h>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just needs me to install VTK library :)